# Equivalent martingale measure in time changed Levy models

Tags: risk-neutral-measure, arbitrage, martingale, heston, real-world-measure

I am investigating time changed Levy models. As far as I have seen, these models are usually directly described under the risk neutral measure $\mathbb{Q}$. However, I'm interested in first modelling the dynamics under the physical measure $\mathbb{P}$ and then using some change of measure to find an EMM. I work in the following framework: First I model the stock price $S(t)$ under the physical measure $\mathbb{P}$ as

$$
S(t):=S(0)\exp(X(t))
$$ 
with an arbitrary Levy process $X(t)$. The time change I use is given by an integrated CIR process, i.e.
$$
T_t = \int_0^t\lambda(s)\mathrm{d}s
$$
with
$$
\mathrm{d}\lambda(t)=\kappa(\theta-\lambda(t))\mathrm{d}t+\eta\sqrt{\lambda(t)}\mathrm{d}W^1(t),\quad \lambda(0)=\lambda_0.
$$
In order to capture the leverage effect, we can allow the Brownian motion $W^1(t)$ driving the intensity $\lambda(t)$ to be correlated with the Brownian motion part of $X(t)$.
The stock price process under the time change is then given by
$$
\tilde S(t):=S(T_t).
$$

To start, I consider the following simple case:
$$
X(t)=\mu t+\sigma \rho W^1(t) + \sigma\sqrt{1-\rho^2}W^2(t)
$$
where $W^1(t)$ and $W^2(t)$ are two independent Brownian motions. In this case $\rho$ controls the leverage.
The time changed price process is then given by
$$
\tilde S(t)=S(0)\exp\left(\mu\int_0^t\lambda(s)\mathrm{d}s+\sigma\rho W^1\left(\int_0^t\lambda(s)\mathrm{d}s\right)+\sigma\sqrt{1-\rho^2} W^2\left(\int_0^t\lambda(s)\mathrm{d}s\right)\right).
$$
In order to exclude arbitrage the discounted stock price process
$$
\exp(-rt)\tilde S(t) = S(0)\exp\left(-rt+\mu\int_0^t\lambda(s)\mathrm{d}s+\sigma\rho W^1\left(\int_0^t\lambda(s)\mathrm{d}s\right)+\sigma\sqrt{1-\rho^2} W^2\left(\int_0^t\lambda(s)\mathrm{d}s\right)\right).
$$
must be a martingale. By the Dubins-Schwarz theorem it holds
$$
W^i\left(\int_0^t \lambda(s)\mathrm{d}s\right)=\int_0^t\sqrt{\lambda(s)}\mathrm{d}W^i(s), \quad i=1,2.
$$
Hence, I can write
$$
\exp(-rt)\tilde S(t)=S(0)\exp\left(-rt+\mu\int_0^t\lambda(s)\mathrm{d}s+\sigma\rho\int_0^t\sqrt{\lambda(s)}\mathrm{d}W^1(s)+\sigma\sqrt{1-\rho^2}\int_0^t\sqrt{\lambda(s)}\mathrm{d}W^2(s)\right)
$$
In order to find a change of measure, I write
$$
\exp(-rt)\tilde S(t)=S(0)\exp\left(-rt+\mu\int_0^t\lambda(s)\mathrm{d}s-\sigma\rho\int_0^t\gamma(s)\sqrt{\lambda(s)}\mathrm{d}s-\sigma\sqrt{1-\rho^2}\int_0^t\delta(s)\sqrt{\lambda(s)}\mathrm{d}s\\
+\sigma\rho\int_0^t\sqrt{\lambda(s)}\mathrm{d}\left(W^1(s)+\int_0^s\gamma(r)\mathrm{d}r\right)\\
+\sigma\sqrt{1-\rho^2}\int_0^t\sqrt{\lambda(s)}\mathrm{d}\left(W^2(s)+\int_0^s\delta(r)\mathrm{d}r\right)\right)
$$
It must now hold that 
$$
-rt+\mu\int_0^t\lambda(s)\mathrm{d}s-\sigma\rho\int_0^t\gamma(s)\sqrt{\lambda(s)}\mathrm{d}s-\sigma\sqrt{1-\rho^2}\int_0^t\delta(s)\sqrt{\lambda(s)}\mathrm{d}s \\
= -\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\int_0^t\lambda(s)\mathrm{d}s
$$
Differentiating both sides gives
$$
-r+\mu\lambda(t)+\sigma\rho\gamma(t)\sqrt{\lambda(t)}-\sigma\sqrt{1-\rho^2}\delta(t)\sqrt{\lambda(t)}=-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\lambda(t).
$$
We set $\gamma(t):=\mu\sqrt{\lambda(t)}$ with arbitrary $\mu\in\mathbb{R}$. Hence, it must hold
$$
\delta(t) = -\frac{r}{\sigma\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}+\frac{(\mu-\sigma\rho+\sigma^2/2)\sqrt{\lambda(t)}}{\sigma\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}
$$
The risk neutral measure can then be defined via
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbb{Q}}{\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}}:=\mathcal{E}(-\gamma(t)\bullet W^1(t)-\delta(t) \bullet W^2(t)).
$$
The dynamics of the intensity under $\mathbb{Q}$ are then given by
$$
\mathrm{d}\lambda(t)=\kappa^*(\theta^*-\lambda(t))\mathrm{d}t+\sigma\sqrt{\lambda(t)}\mathrm{d}W^1(t)
$$
with $\kappa^*=\kappa+\eta\mu$ and $\theta^*=\frac{\kappa\theta}{\kappa+\eta\mu}$.
Now my questions:

- Is the whole argument sound?
- In the part where I used the Dubins-Schwarz theorem, can I really use **the same** Brownian on both sides of the equation? In the theorem it says that there is **some** Brownian motion such that it holds. But if it isn't the same brownian motion I have no clue on how to proceed.
- With respect to which filtration is the discounted stock price a martingale under $\mathbb{Q}$? I guess it must be $\mathcal{G}_t:=\sigma\left(W^i(T_s), T_s; 0\leq s\leq t\right)$ . How can I make this rigorous?